# Not defined database schema

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-schema

I have a mysql database with 220 tables. The database is will structured but without any clear relations. I want to find a way to connect the primary key of each table to its correspondent foreign key.
I was thinking to write a script to discover the possible relation between two columns:

- The content range should be similar in both of them
- The foreign key name could be similar to the primary key table name

Those features are not sufficient to solve the problem. Do you have any idea how I could be more accurate and close to the solution. Also, If there's any available tool which do that.

Please Advice!

Comment: (1) Doesn't MyNONsql have a catalogue, that can be accessed via their NONsql, in order to obtain PK::FK references ??? Every SQL that I have worked with does, it is an SQL Compliance requirement. (2) If it doesn't have "clear relations", that is proof that it is not "well structured".

Comment: It's well structured in term of content data, data is well connected. That may come from application level. On the other hand, I need to enhance the database by finding the functional dependency between the tables.

Comment: Ok, so myNONsql has no catalogue, thus it is not an SQL.  Ok, so (x) the data is well-structured but (a) the structure is unknown and (b) it cannot be identified.  (x) is in violent contradiction with (a) and (b).

Comment: I added more detail and explanation, please review.  Feel free to ask question in the comments, or add detail to the question (use an **EDIT** section).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a licensed app+RFS, and you want to save the data (which is an asset that belongs to the organisation), and ditch the app (due to the problems having exceeded the threshold of acceptability).

Happens all the time.  Until something like this happens, people do not appreciate that their **data is precious**, that it out-lives any app, good or bad, in-house or third-party.

#### SQL Platform

If it was an honest SQL platform, it would have the SQL-compliant catalogue, and the catalogue would contain an entry for each reference.  The catalogue is an entry-level SQL Compliance requirement.  The code required to access the catalogue and extract the FOREIGN KEY declarations is simple, and it is written in SQL.

- Unless you are saying "there are no Referential Integrity constraints, it is all controlled from the app layers", which means it is not a database, it is a data storage location, a Record Filing System, a slave of the app.
- In that case, your data has no Referential Integrity

#### Pretend SQL Platform

Evidently non-compliant databases such as MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle fraudulently position themselves as "SQL", but they do not have basic SQL functionality, such as a catalogue.  I suppose you get what you pay for.

### Solution

For (a) such databases, such as your MySQL, and (b) data placed in an honest SQL container that has no FOREIGN KEY declarations, I would use one of two methods.

#### Solution 1

First preference.

- use `awk`
- load each table into an array
- write scripts to:

  - determine the Keys (if your "keys" are `ID` fields, you are stuffed, details below)
  - determine any references between the Keys of the arrays

#### Solution 2

Now you *could* do all that in SQL, but then, the code would be horrendous, and SQL is not designed for that (table comparisons).  Which is why I would use `awk`, in which case the code (for an experienced coder) is complex (given 220 files) but straight-forward.  That is squarely within `awk`s design and purpose.  It would take far less development time.

I wouldn't attempt to provide code here, there are too many dependencies to identify, it would be premature and primitive.

#### Relational Keys

Relational Keys, as required by Codd's *Relational Model*, relate ("link", "map", "connect") each row in each table to the rows in any other table that it is related to, by Key.  These Keys are natural Keys, and usually compound Keys.  Keys are logical identifiers of the data. Thus, writing either `awk` programs or SQL code to determine:

- the Keys
- the occurrences of the Keys elsewhere
- and thus the dependencies

is a pretty straight-forward matter, because the Keys are visible, recognisable as such.

This is also very important for data that is exported from the database to some other system (which is precisely what we are trying to do here).   The **Keys have meaning**, to the organisation, and that meaning is beyond the database.  Thus importation is easy.  Codd wrote about this value specifically in the *RM*.

This is just one of the many scenarios where the value of Relational Keys, the absolute need for them, is appreciated.

#### Non-keys

Conversely, if your Record Filing System has no Relational Keys, then you are stuffed, and stuffed big time.  The `IDs` are in fact record numbers in the files.  They all have the same range, say 1 to 1 million. It is not reasonably possible to relate any given record number in one file to its occurrences in any other file, because **record numbers have no meaning**.

Record numbers are physical, they do not identify the data.

> *I see a record number* 123456 *being repeated in the Invoice file, now what* other *file does this relate to ? Every other* possible *file, Supplier, Customer, Part, Address, CreditCard, where it occurs once only, has a record number* 123456 !

Whereas with Relational Keys:

> *I see* IBM *plus a sequence* 1, 2, 3, ... *in the Invoice table, now what* other *table does this relate to ? The only table that has* IBM *occurring once is the Customer table.*

The moral of the story, to etch into one's mind, is this.  Actually there are a few, even when limiting them to the context of this Question:

- If you want a Relational Database, **use Relational Keys**, *do not use Record IDs*
- If you want Referential Integrity, **use Relational Keys**, *do not use Record IDs*
- If your data is precious, **use Relational Keys**, *do not use Record IDs*
- If you want to export/import your data, **use Relational Keys**, *do not use Record IDs*